# Regex : Split on comma , but exclude commas within parentheses and quotes(Both single & Double)

Tags: java, regex

I have one string

```
5,(5,5),C'A,B','A,B',',B','A,',"A,B",C"A,B"
```

I want to split it on comma but need to exclude commas within parentheses and quotes(Both single and double quotes).

Like this

`5` `(5,5)` `C'A,B'` `'A,B'` `',B'` `'A,'` `"A,B"` `C"A,B"`

Using java Regular Expression how to achieve this ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
String input = "5,(5,5),C'A,B','A,B',',B','A,',\"A,B\",C\"A,B\"";
String[] toks = input.split( 
                ",(?=(([^']*'){2})*[^']*$)(?=(([^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$)(?![^()]*\\))" );
for (String tok: toks)
    System.out.printf("<%s>%n", tok);
```

**Output:**

```
<5>
<(5,5)>
<C'A,B'>
<'A,B'>
<',B'>
<'A,'>
<"A,B">
<C"A,B">
```

**Explanation:**

```
,                         # Match literal comma
(?=(([^']*'){2})*[^']*$)  # Lookahead to ensure comma is followed by even number of '
(?=(([^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)  # Lookahead to ensure comma is followed by even number of "
(?![^()]*\\))             # Negative lookahead to ensure ) is not followed by matching
                          # all non [()] characters in between
```

Comment: If i am giving nested parentheses its spiting on comma which is inside bracket...5(5,5(5,R5)).

Comment: This is not for **nested bracket** string. No regex can help you in that.

Answer (score 2):

```
,(?![^(]*\))(?![^"']*["'](?:[^"']*["'][^"']*["'])*[^"']*$)
```

Try this.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/uC8uO6/3).

For java

```
,(?![^(]*\\))(?![^"']*["'](?:[^"']*["'][^"']*["'])*[^"']*$)
```

Comment: Eclipse its showing --invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )

Comment: @anupammaiti `,(?![^(]*\\))(?![^"']*["'](?:[^"']*["'][^"']*["'])*[^"']*$)`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `split`ting the string, consider matching instead.

```
String s  = "5,(5,5),C'A,B','A,B',',B','A,',\"A,B\",C\"A,B\"";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:[^,]*(['\"])[^'\"]*\\1|\\([^)]*\\))|[^,]+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Output

```
5
(5,5)
C'A,B'
'A,B'
',B'
'A,'
"A,B" 
C"A,B"
```