# Split string by comma if not within square brackets or parentheses

Tags: java, regex

I have a long string, and I want to set it to an array by splitting it by the comma as long as the comma is not within square brackets or parentheses. I've tried a couple of variations but not getting exactly what I'm looking for...

Example 1:

```
Harry Potter, Hermione, (Severus, Snape)
Returns:
Harry Potter
Hermione
Severus, Snape
```

Example 2:

```
Harry Potter, [and, the chamber, of secrets], Hermione, (Olivanders, Wands)
Returns:
Harry Potter
and, the chamber, of secrets
Hermione
Olivanders, Wands
```

Comment: @Marc - I saw that question, but it still wasn't clear to me how to account for both of the conditions I'm looking for.

Comment: Reopened since this question is about brackets **and** parentheses: a full answer is harder.

Comment: @Bathsheba http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28587081/regex-split-on-comma-but-exclude-commas-within-parentheses-and-quotesboth-s

Comment: Nice spot but IMHO it's worth answering that specifically, although your well-found answer might be sufficient for the OP.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the following regex with global flag.

```
,(?![^\(\[]*[\]\)])
```

Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/fG4iG6/1).
It is inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/9030062/1630604.