# Regular expression for word *not* in specific latex command

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regular expression which will match all occurrences of `foo` unless it is in a `\ref{..}` command. So `\ref{sec:foo}` should not match.

I will probably want to add more commands for which the arguments should be excluded later so the solution should be extendable in that regard.

There are some similar questions trying to detect when something is in parenthesis, etc.

- [Regex to match only commas not in parentheses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030036/regex-to-match-only-commas-not-in-parentheses)
- [Split string by comma if not within square brackets or parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38747776/split-string-by-comma-if-not-within-square-brackets-or-parentheses?noredirect=1&lq=1)

The first has an interesting solution using alternatives: `\(.*?\)|(,)` the first alternative matches the unwanted versions and the second has the match group. However, since I am using this is in a search&replace context I cannot really use match groups.

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Finding a regex for what you want will need variable length look behind which is only available with very limited languages (like C# and PyPi in Python) hence you will have to settle with a less than perfect. You can use this regex to match `foo` that is not within curly braces as long as you don't have curly nested curly braces,

```
\bfoo\b(?![^{}]*})
```

This will not match a `foo` inside `\ref{sec:foo}` or even in `somethingelse{sec:foo}` as you can see it only doesn't match a `foo` that isn't contained in a curly braces. If you need a precise solution, then it will need variable length look behind support which as I said, is available in very limited languages.

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ez99mJ/1)**

Comment: Yeah, that's what the other answers suggest as well but it's not really what I want because I want to make sure I know all the latex commands in which it appears as a parameter.

Comment: In that case, I'll suggest you to go for a custom parser. Safe and efficient.

Comment: I'm not sure writing a custom parser for latex can be done in an efficient way. ;)

Comment: I don't know about `latex` but if you can give me some idea, perhaps I can try helping you. Like, show me some sample data and your expected output out of that data?